# C# Changing a string after it has been created

Tags: c#, immutability

Okay I know this question is painfully simple, and I'll admit that I am pretty new to C# as well.  But the title doesn't describe the entire situation here so hear me out.

I need to alter a URL string which is being created in a C# code behind, removing the substring ".aspx" from the end of the string.  So basically I know that my URL, coming into this class, will be something like "Blah.aspx" and I want to get rid of the ".aspx" part of that string.  I assume this is quite easy to do by just finding that substring, and removing it if it exists (or some similar strategy, would appreciate if someone has an elegant solution for it if they've thought done it before).  Here is the problem:

"Because strings are immutable, it is not possible (without using unsafe code) to modify the value of a string object after it has been created."  This is from the MSDN official website.  So I'm wondering now, if strings are truly immutable, then I simply can't (shouldn't) alter the string after it has been made.  So how can I make sure that what I'm planning to do is safe?

Comment: You can't alter a string (and you shouldn't). But you can easily create a new string based on the old one. When you call `SubString`, a new string is created for you.

Comment: If it's "Blah.aspx?query=yup" what should the result be?

Comment: Unfortunately, I just figured out that the string is getting the .aspx added onto it AFTER leaving this class... so now I am stuck again searching through to see where this happens.  My problem is that I am making the URL look like "Blah?ID=100.aspx", which is incorrect.

Comment: Still I believe my original question has been answered. Still looking at all answers now, they all seem to be correct in their own right.

Comment: If you want to do a lot of manipulations on strings it is better to use a `StringBuilder`, which *is* mutable. That way you avoid generating new strings for every insert/replace operation. In your case, the `Uri`/`UriBuilder` classes might be useful.

Comment: @mikez That can be overly expensive for small operations.  There's still copying going on regardless.

Comment: @DonBoitnott - I'd take "most likely producing correct results for all encoding" over "overly expensive" on any day. `Uri`/`UriBuilder`/`Path` classes generally can handle Uri manipulation scenarios in much more self-documenting and more likely to be correct way.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov You're probably right.  I was thinking mostly about `StringBuilder`.  I should have been more specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

String immutability is not a problem for normal usage -- it just means that member functions like "Replace", instead of modifying the existing string object, return a new one.  In practical terms that usually just means you have to remember to copy the change back to the original, like:

```
string x = "Blah.aspx";
x.Replace(".aspx", "");       // still "Blah.aspx"
x = x.Replace(".aspx", "");   // now "Blah"
```

The weirdness around strings comes from the fact that `System.String` inherits `System.Object`, yet, because of its immutability, behaves like a value type rather than an object.  For example, if you pass a string into a function, there's no way to modify it, unless you pass it by reference:

```
void Test(string y)
{
    y = "bar";
}
void Test(ref string z)
{
    z = "baz";
}
string x = "foo";
Test(x);                 // x is still "foo"
Test(ref x);             // x is now "baz"
```

Comment: The OP appears to only want to remove it if it's at the end, not if it's anywhere.

Comment: @Servy in that case, you could use a Regex that specifies that there is nothing after the .aspx. ".aspx$" would do it.

Comment: @KyleRogers You could, if you wanted to, but that's swatting a fly with a sledgehammer.

Comment: This actually ended up doing what I needed, so I selected this as the answer.  For those below, I'm still going to study what each of you said and thank you for the comments.

Comment: `String` does *not* behave like a value type, in any sense of the word.  It is a reference type, and behaves like a reference type in all situations (because that's what it is).  Immutability has *nothing* to to with value/reference types.  Value types can be either mutable or immutable, and reference types can be either mutable or immutable.

Answer (score 6):

You don't change the string, you change the variable.  Instead of that variable referring to a string such as `"foo.aspx"`, alter it to point to a new string that has the value `"foo"`.

As an analogy, adding one to the number two doesn't *change* the number two.  Two is still just the same as it always way, you have changed a variable from referring to one number to refer to another.

As for your specific case, `EndsWith` and `Remove` make it easy enough:

```
if (url.EndsWith(".aspx"))
    url = url.Remove(url.Length - ".aspx".Length);
```

Note here that `Remove` is taking one string, an integer, and *giving us a brand new string*, which we need to assign back to our variable.  It doesn't change the string itself.

Also note that there is a [URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class that you can use for parsing URLs, and it will be able to handle all of the complex situations that can arise, including hashes, query parameters, etc.  You should use that to parse out the aspects of a URL that you are interested in.

Answer (score 2):

A `String` in C# is immutable, as you say.  Meaning that this would create multiple `String` objects in memory:

```
String s = "String of numbers 0";
s += "1";
s += "2";
```

So, while the variable `s` would return to you the value `String of numbers 012`, internally it required the creation of three strings in memory to accomplish.

In your particular case, the solution is quite simple:

```
String myPath = "C:\\folder1\\folder2\\myFile.aspx";
myPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(myPath), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(myPath));
```

Again, this appears as if `myPath` has changed, but it really has not.  An internal copy and assign took place and you get to keep using the same variable.

Also, if you must preserve the original variable, you could simply make a new variable:

```
String myPath = "C:\\folder1\\folder2\\myFile.aspx";
String thePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(myPath), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(myPath));
```

Either way, you end up with a variable you can use.

Note that the use of the `Path` methods ensures you get proper path operations, and not blind `String` replacements that could have unintended side-effects.

Answer (score 1):

`String.Replace()` will not modify the string. It will create a new one. So the following code:

```
String myUrl = @"http://mypath.aspx";
String withoutExtension = myUrl.Replace(".aspx", "");
```

will create a brand-new string which is assigned to withoutExtension.

Comment: Don't forget that if you realize after posting that another answer (that's better or the same) has already been posted, there's no cost to deleting your post in order to avoid cluttering questions with answers that don't add anything.